# What is the difference between testing enterprise grade mobile Apps and regular apps? What are they?

Tags: mobile

I know what are native and web apps but I don't understand what are enterprise mobile apps means?

Comment: enterprise apps are building using enterprisey code, so they're highly overengineered, highly buggy, and generally useless for anyone except the specific enterprise who commissioned  the app in the first place, and usually useless for the specific enterprise as well.

Comment: Do you think testing entreprise apps are more difficult than regular apps?